# Give back all rows from certain type based on only one criteria in another column

Tags: r, excel

I got the following dataset.

```
  Name  Date       AC   AD   Value
   A    2008-04               -0.5
   A    2008-06                  3
   A    2009-05               -0.8
   A    2010-04               -0.6
   B    2005-04                  2
   B    2006-05                  2
   B    2010-08                 -1
   C    2012-05                  2
   D    2016-05                  5
   D    2017-05                  6
```

I am interested in the negative numbers in my column value.
I am looking for a code that gives me back all the rows from the Name A if at least one of the numbers in my column value is negative.

So in the example above, I am interested in all the 4 rows of A and the 3 rows of B, but I do not want to get the rows from C and D because for all of their observations there is no negative value.

```
  Name  Date       AC   AD   Value
   A    2008-04               -0.5
   A    2008-06                  3
   A    2009-05                  4
   A    2010-04               -0.6
   B    2005-04                  2
   B    2006-05                  2
   B    2010-08                 -1
   B    2012-05                  2
   C    2016-05                  5
   C    2017-05                  6
```

Can that be expressed in a code
Thank you :)

Comment: It is not clear about the expected output.  How did -0.8 changed to 4?  Is there any significance for `AC` and `AD` blank columns? `but I do not want to get the rows from C and D because for all of their observations there is no negative value` then why the expected output shows `C` rows as well\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, grouped by 'Name' `if` `any` 'Value' is less than 0, then get the subset of data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(any(Value <0)) .SD, Name]
#   Name    Date Value
#1:    A 2008-04  -0.5
#2:    A 2008-06   3.0
#3:    A 2009-05  -0.8
#4:    A 2010-04  -0.6
#5:    B 2005-04   2.0
#6:    B 2006-05   2.0
#7:    B 2010-08  -1.0
```

---

Or with `subset` fromm `base R`

```
subset(df1, Name %in% names(which(!!table(df1[,1], df1[,3] < 0)[,2])))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"D", "D"), Date = c("2008-04", "2008-06", "2009-05", "2010-04", 
"2005-04", "2006-05", "2010-08", "2012-05", "2016-05", "2017-05"
 ), Value = c(-0.5, 3, -0.8, -0.6, 2, 2, -1, 2, 5, 6)),
 class =   data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: I have never seen this !!table structure.  What is happening there?

Comment: @J.Win. With the first `!`  all the 0 values becomes TRUE and other becomes FALSE.  The second `!` reverses that so that we get 'Names' that have at least one negative value

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ave` with `any` to select if any of the rows for group `Name` has value less than 0 and select those groups.

```
df[ave(df$Value < 0, df$Name, FUN = any), ]

#  Name    Date Value
#1    A 2008-04  -0.5
#2    A 2008-06   3.0
#3    A 2009-05  -0.8
#4    A 2010-04  -0.6
#5    B 2005-04   2.0
#6    B 2006-05   2.0
#7    B 2010-08  -1.0
```

---

and an equivalent `dplyr` operation using `filter` would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Name) %>%
   filter(any(Value < 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an easy one line solution usic basic R code:

```
df[df$Name %in% unique(df[df$Value<0,"Name"]),]
  Name Value
1    A  -0.5
2    A   3.0
3    A  -0.8
4    A  -0.6
5    B   2.0
6    B   2.0
7    B  -1.0
```

Minimal input data:

```
df<-data.frame(Name=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","D","D"),
               Value=c(-0.5,3,-0.8,-0.6,2,2,-1,2,5,6))
```